# Why the decision tree shows a correct classificationthe while some instances are being misclassified

Tags: classification, weka, decision-tree, prediction

I am using WEKA, 10-fold cross validation or split 66% to create training and testing sets .. I used c4.5 (J48) as a classifier .. 
I get in my results that some instances are misclassified, but, when I visualize the tree I see that based on the tree the instances should have been classified correctly !!!

I don't see this when the testing set is the same training set .. if the classifier decided to  create such a tree why some instances are not being classified based on this tree ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the decision tree shows a correct classification while some instances are being misclassified

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are after a completely unpruned tree such that the Training Data should return a 100% accuracy.

The options that are likely causing the undesirable results are outlined below:

- **Unpruned** is used to minimise the number of rules in the decision tree and can lead to lower generalisation error
- **minNumObj** is used to determine the minimum number of cases required to make a rule.  If this is higher than one, you could get some errors on the training data.

I wouldn't generally recommend using these options for a given problem, but if you are trying to obtain a 100% result on the training data, this would be the place to start.

Hope this helps!